# ios coding - how to download music from my server and store it in Music

Tags: ios

I know how to download an audio file and save it within the app.
But how can I put the downloaded music directly in to my ipod music so that I can play it directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible without a jailbreak.